# What are the steps to integrate a new mailman list?

Tags: sendmail, mailman

I am using Mailman version 2.1.12 running on a Linux CentOS 6.3 final system, and there are already many successfully operational mailman lists in operation. sendmail is the transport.

I have created a new list -- using `newlist` for the administrator/moderator; subscribed to it; and confirmed using the web interface. However, I cannot send mail to the list. Our email system says there is no such address.

I remembered that /etc/aliases has to be updated (example below), which was not automatically done when I ran `newlist`.

```
##special_education_news mailing list
special_education_news: "|/usr/lib/mailman/mail/mailman post special_education_news"
```

so I made sure the list name entries (bounces and so on) were added, and I restarted sendmail. I still cannot send email to the list.

I really have been searching on the web for the steps and cannot find something that will list out the steps to take after creating a new list. I would appreciate a pointer to that information and/or an answer here.

Comment: Have you read the mailman documentation?

Comment: I have read some of it, not all. I am trying to locate the documentation for integrating a new list.

Comment: How did you go about creating the list? If you use the [`newlist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/site.html) command it should do all the mailman-specific stuff that needs doing, and tell you what else you need to do like updating `/etc/aliases` (I think it even gives you the stuff you need to paste into your aliases file?)

Comment: I did use newlist, but it not update /etc/aliases. As my answer states I restarted two services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did use newlist to create the new list. I found /etc/aliases was not updated. After adding the various email addresses to /etc/aliases and restarting sendmail, I found I also had to restart mailman. Then my email went through.